# Discord py delete voicechannel if its empty

Tags: discord.py

Well im trying to create a voice channel by command so i can join it.
And as soon i leave the channel its supposed to get deleted.

What i tried:

```
if message.content.startswith('/voice'):
    guild = message.guild
    voicechannel = await guild.create_voice_channel(f"{str(message.author)}")
    await asyncio.sleep(5)

    while True:
       if len(voicechannel.voice_states) == 0:
           await voicechannel.delete()
           break
```

doesnt even work tho

Comment: What doesn't work? Please [edit] your question to include debugging details. See [ask] for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that your issue is that you are stuck in an infinite `while True` loop. I would first suggest that you switch to using `discord.ext.commands`, it simplifies the process of creating a Discord Bot by a great deal. If you were using `discord.ext.commands.Bot`, you would be able to use the `wait_for()` function to wait until the voice channel is empty.

```py
from discord.ext.commands import Bot

client = Bot(command_prefix="/")

@client.command(name="voice")
async def voice(ctx):
    guild = ctx.guild
    voice_channel = await guild.create_voice_channel(f"{str(ctx.author)}")

    def check(member, before, after):
        return member == ctx.author and before.channel == voice_channel and after.channel is None

    await client.wait_for("voice_state_update", check=check)
    await voice_channel.delete()

client.run("TOKEN")
```

The only issue that I think could happen, is if the member never joins the voice channel. To counter this, we can set up another `wait_for()` function to determine if the member ever joins before waiting for the member to leave the voice channel.

```py
from asyncio import TimeoutError

@client.command(name="voice")
async def voice(ctx):
    guild = ctx.guild
    voice_channel = await guild.create_voice_channel(f"{str(ctx.author)}")

    def check(member, before, after):
        return member == ctx.author and before.channel is None and after.channel == voice_channel

    try:
        await client.wait_for("voice_state_update", check=check, timeout=60)
    except TimeoutError:
        await voice_channel.delete()
        return
```

Comment: Uhm its me again the Part with the timeout doesnt work.
I get this Error:


`
File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 458, in 
wait_for
    raise exceptions.TimeoutError() from exc
asyncio.exceptions.TimeoutError
`
I have no idea what that tells me

Comment: @Rekutor ensure that you have properly imported `asyncio.TimeoutError`.